# QGamepadManager does not detect controller disconnection on ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gamepad

I am working on a Qt project with a drone. Me and my friends are controlling a drone with a Xbox 360 Controller.

So to detect buttons and axes we have used the QGamepadManager class which is in the gamepadmanager module. It works well ! But we have a problem with this simplified code :

```
while (true)
{
    if (this->gamepad->isConnected()) {
        cout << "gamepad connected" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "gamepad disocnnected" << endl;
    }
}


bool GamepadMonitor::isConnected()
{
    return QGamepadManager::instance()->connectedGamepads().size() == 1;
}
```

On windows, the method `isConnected()` works well but not on Ubuntu. When we launch the application with the gamepad connected the buttons are recognized and axis too. But the disconnection is not detected. When we launch the application without the gamepad, the connection is not recognized.

I have installed the `joystick` package. I am on Ubuntu 16.04. I am developping with Qt 5.8.

Do you have an idea ?

**EDIT :** I add the dmesg output

When I connect the gamepad :

```
[  330.430405] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  330.575708] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=028e
[  330.575714] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  330.575718] usb 3-1: Product: Controller
[  330.575721] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: ©Microsoft Corporation
[  330.575723] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1E69441
[  331.614141] input: Microsoft X-Box 360 pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input23
[  331.622581] usbcore: registered new interface driver xpad
```

When I disconnect it :

```
[  392.733786] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  392.733995] xpad 3-1:1.0: xpad_try_sending_next_out_packet - usb_submit_urb failed with result -19
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand checking if Ubuntu itself detects the disconnection, by looking at the game state, or directly at `dmesg` output.

As it probably is detecting it, I encourage you to then fill a bug report on [Qt tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG/fixforversion/15700/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel) :)

Comment: I checked this, when I do a `dmesg | grep X-Box`, there is one line per USB connection but I don't know if it is normal or not. Each time the input change

Comment: Ok, my question was what happens when you disconnect your gamepad ? Is it logged in dmesg ?

Comment: did anybody ever learn anything about this issue?  I have encountered the same problem.  I have tried Qt 5.11, and there is no change